# Declaring timestamp in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, datetime, stored-procedures

I have to insert a timestamp value into a table. I am inserting values by writing an stored procedure.
This is the code to my stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dataInsert_Schedule() RETURNS boolean As
$$
DECLARE
    i integer;
    j integer;
    dur integer;
    tup Channel%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR tup IN SELECT * FROM Channel
    LOOP
        for i in 0..6 LOOP --days
            for j in 0..23 LOOP  --hours
                dur = round((random() * 2) + 1);
                IF i + dur > 24 then
                    dur = 24 - i;
                END IF;
                INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES(tup.Channel_ID, round((random() * 999) + 1),( current_date + (integer to_char(i,'9')) )+ (interval to_char(j,'99') || ' hour'), (interval  dur ||' hour'));
                i = i + dur - 1;
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    return true;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I write the query `Select * From dataInsert_Schedule();` I got the following error :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to_char"
LINE 1: ...d((random() * 999) + 1),( current_date + (integer to_char( $...
                                                             ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES( $1 , round((random() * 999) + 1),( current_date + (integer to_char( $2 ,'9')) )+ (interval to_char( $3 ,'99') || ' hour'), (interval  $4  ||' hour'))
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "datainsert_schedule" near line 15

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "to_char"
SQL state: 42601
Context: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "datainsert_schedule" near line 15
```

I First tried this

> `INSERT INTO Schedule VALUES(tup.Channel_ID, round((random() * 999) + 1),( current_date + (integer ''||i) )+ (interval (j ||' hour')), (interval  dur ||' hour'));`

way of inserting, but I was getting the same kind of error.

**Why I am getting this error?**

And the `schedule` table is defined as following:

```
CREATE TABLE Schedule(
Channel_ID Integer  REFERENCES Channel(Channel_ID),
Program_ID Integer  REFERENCES Program(Program_ID),
Start_Time Timestamp NOT NULL,
Duration Interval NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Schedule_Key PRIMARY KEY(Channel_ID, Program_ID)
);
```

Comment: Adding create for Channel table would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me like this:

```
select (to_char(1,'99') || ' hour')::interval;
```

You don't need the `to_char`:

```
select (1 || ' hour')::interval;
 interval 
----------
 01:00:00
```

So this would be it:

```
INSERT INTO Schedule
VALUES (
tup.Channel_ID,
round((random() * 999) + 1),
(current_date + i::integer) + (j || ' hour')::interval,
(dur ||' hour')::interval
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A type name may be specified before a string constant to cast it into this type, but it applies only to constants. So `integer '123'` is fine but `integer to_char(something)` or `interval column_name` are not permitted, which is why your query fails.

This is explained in the SQL syntax chapter from the manual, specifically this paragraph: [Constants of Other Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC).
Excerpt:

> A constant of an arbitrary type can be entered using any one of the
>   following notations:
>
> type 'string'
>   'string'::type
>   CAST ( 'string' AS type )

and below:

> The ::, CAST(), and function-call syntaxes can also be used to specify
>   run-time type conversions of arbitrary expressions

The point relevant to the question being that `type 'string'` notation is not included in the syntaxes that can accept arbitrary expressions, contrary to `::` and `cast()`.